# Saving an assignment made within a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I have this code:

```
x = 9
def changex():
    x = 10
    return x
changex()
print x
```

when I print x it doesn't say that it is 10, how do I make it so that it is 10 without doing print changex()? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, if you want code from inside a function to affect global variables, you need to add a `global` statement:

```
x = 9
def changex():
    global x
    x = 10
    return x
changex()
print x
```

Comment: thanks , I didn't know global could be used to bring in a variable that's outside of a function

Comment: Aside: your use of `return` here is unnecessary. I didn't remove it because I didn't know if you thought it was germane to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the `x` object, but you *can* redefine it:

```
x = changex()
print x
```

You could also put `global x` at the beginning of the function so that it will be redefining the global variable instead of defining a local one.